# Optimization of create/run multiple SQLalchemy Engines?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, mysql-python

Assuming I have 30 databases in MySQL from db1 to db30. I have a python script that will create engine and connect to *one* db,

```
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv('pricelist.csv')

new_df = df[['date','time','new_price']]

engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://root:python@localhost:3306/db1', echo = False)

new_df.to_sql(name='temporary_table', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)

with engine.begin() as cnx:
    sql_insert_query_new = 'REPLACE INTO newlist (SELECT * FROM temporary_table)'
    cnx.execute(sql_insert_query_new)
    cnx.execute("DROP TABLE temporary_table")
```

Now with the above script, I will need to have 30 python scripts to create engine and connect each db to conduct the query. And to call these 30 scripts, I will need to use a batch file on a task scheduler.

Is there an optimize way of connecting to multiple databases with a single script? I read up on sessions and don't think it is able to take in multiple databases. And if I have 30 python scripts doing this creation engine and connection, will there be any issue in terms of processing performance? Eventually, I will have like hundreds of db in MySQL.

Thanks!

Note: Each database has their own unique table names.

Using Python 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I think may be you can do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import MySQLdb
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

df = pd.read_csv('pricelist.csv')

new_df = df[['date','time','new_price']]
db_names = [f'db{i}' for i in range(1, 31)]
table_names = ['temporary_table', 'table_name_2', 'table_name_3', ...]

for db, tb in zip(db_names, table_names):
    engine = create_engine(f'mysql+mysqldb://root:python@localhost:3306/{db}', echo=False)

    new_df.to_sql(name=tb, con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)

    with engine.begin() as cnx:
        sql_insert_query_new = f'REPLACE INTO newlist (SELECT * FROM {tb})'
        cnx.execute(sql_insert_query_new)
        cnx.execute(f"DROP TABLE {tb}")
```

Comment: Thanks Waket. This looks like a possibility - I will need to try it when I am home later. However, the database tables for each db are unique. I foresee that this for iteration will output an error due to the table naming? Sorry if this isn't clear from my initial question. *Updated my question*

Comment: I have tried to connect two db using the above. However it is giving me error sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1049, "Unknown database '('db1',)'"). I don't think this works. Do you know whether running multiple scripts and creating/connecting to each db will cause performance issues?

Comment: You can run `mysql -uroot -ppython` and then `show databases` to list the databases

Comment: Sorry I don't follow you - and the answer does not seem to answer my questions. I already know all my databases name and declared it in the db_names.